# What's a good way to view dojo's javascript source files in Eclipse with Aptana?

Tags: eclipse, dojo, aptana, code-formatting

I have Aptana installed within Eclipse. I'm working on a project with the dojo 1.2 JavaScript library installed.

When I open one of dojo's dijit .js files, the code is formatted in a rather difficult to read way. The Eclipse "Outline" view shows a list of functions with names like "_2" and "ew". Not very human friendly.

I'm talking about source code that looks like this:

> dojo.declare("dijit.InlineEditBox",dijit._Widget,{editing:false,autoSave:true,buttonSave:"",buttonCancel:"",renderAsHtml:false,editor:"dijit.form.TextBox",editorParams:{},onChange:function(_1){
>   },onCancel:function(){
>   },width:"100%",value:"",noValueIndicator:"    ✍    ",constructor:function(){
>   this.editorParams={};
>   },postMixInProperties:function(){
>   this.inherited(arguments);
>   this.displayNode=this.srcNodeRef;
>   var _2={ondijitclick:"_onClick",onmouseover:"_onMouseOver",onmouseout:"_onMouseOut",onfocus:"_onMouseOver",onblur:"_onMouseOut"};
>   for(var _3 in _2){
>   this.connect(this.displayNode,_3,_2[_3]);
>   }
>   dijit.setWaiRole(this.displayNode,"button");
>   if(!this.displayNode.getAttribute("tabIndex")){
>   this.displayNode.setAttribute("tabIndex",0);
>   }
>   this.attr("value",this.value||this.displayNode.innerHTML);
>   },setDisabled:function(_4){
>   dojo.deprecated("dijit.InlineEditBox.setDisabled() is deprecated.  Use attr('disabled', bool) instead.","","2.0");
>   this.attr("disabled",_4);

How do I get a clearer, "friendlier" view of such a .js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to download uncompressed versions of the library at [dojotoolkit.org](http://www.dojotoolkit.org).
[Here](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.2.2/dojo-release-1.2.2/) is the source tree for 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the dojo source distribution because the "standard" release is compressed with dojo ShrinkSafe tool (something similar to yui compress method based on Rhino) that is 100% safe and saves about 20% space usage. Within the source archive you will find an Util folder full with utils tools for unit testing, compressing, building and documenting :)

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/ - here you will find a list of all downloadable  distributions